# CSS rule is not applied to HTML element

Tags: html, css

I made a, how is it called: stripped down version of my problem.

## http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/hxjp9jL9/1/

## HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="navigationRelative">
    <span data-href="about.1.0.0" data-alt="About" title="About" class="ueber link">    </span>
    <span data-href="artikel.1.0.1" data-alt="Artikel" title="Artikel" class="artikel link"></span>
    <span data-href="person.1.0.2" data-alt="Person" title="Person" class="person link">    </span>
  </div>    
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  left: 172.446px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 84px;
  height: 33px;
  background:green;
}
.navigationRelative {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 80px; 
}
.navigation span {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

The `.navigation` CSS is not applied.

What is this?

I need it for an order.

**Hint:** The error is seemingly not in the HTML -> the `.navigation span` rule is applied!?!

Would be absolutely moshpit, if you could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you did, but the space after .navigation is *not* a normal space. If you replace it with a new typed space it works, otherwise not.

```
.navigation {   /* removed previous "space" and typed space in */
  position: absolute;
  left: 172.446px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 84px;
  height: 33px;
  background:green;
}
```

The original space was a non breaking space (0xa0) when it should have been a normal space (0x20). See an [ASCII table](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) fro reference.

Comment: I basically use SUBLIME 2. Maybe it spit out something while offering the brackets, or so. The file was fresh. There was no hint for `.navigation`... or so. I remember.

Comment: That's like the weirdest bug I've ever seen happening to a css file.

Comment: I took your answer as the marked, because you made some effort to find that actual character-code.

Comment: Yep, it is. Took me off a day.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) between your CSS class name and your opening bracket. Replace it with a regular space, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The unbreakable space `&nbsp` is causing problem in your css, as in image below

[image]